# Calling Audio in background on receiving Push Notification

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have implemented AVAudioPlayer on didReceiveRemoteNotification fetchCompletionHandler Where it plays audio on receiving Push Notification.

However my app is rejected saying

> Your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in
>   your Info.plist but did not include features that require persistent
>   audio.
>
> **Next Steps**
>
> The audio key is intended for use by apps that provide audible content to the user while in the background, such as music player or
>   streaming audio apps. Please revise your app to provide audible
>   content to the user while the app is in the background or remove the
>   "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.

I have found apple doesn’t allow this.. as default it will allow 30seconds to lay sound on receiving notification..I Need to be play sound continuously until user opens the app .Is their any solution for it?

Comment: No there is not solution for your requirement except settings a couple of local notification that repeat to get the user attention. But this might also be reject because Apple does not allow this kind apps that try to get the users attention.

Comment: This is not Mandatory user can stop it in settings of the app

Comment: Well there is no way to do this, the audio background key is for apps that play audio, like a webradio stream of music app. But you can't use it for playing audio upon receiving a push notification. Thus you will need to user multiple local notifications that play back to back and schedule them when you receive the push notification.

Comment: Is there any chance with local notifications that can be accpeted by apple team

Comment: It might. You never can tell

Comment: May i know how can i acheive this with Local notification, We will be having 30Sec limit for local notification.  I need to play sound till user selects the notifications..How can i fire Local notification?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use background audio play.

1. For playing or performing any task in background you can use background task with expiration handler : https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started
2. Implement UNUserNotifications for local notifications :
   https://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/
3. Use NSTimer to perform sound task and show local notifications for 30 sec or 1 minute depend on your requirement.
4. https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary: for system sounds that you play in background